Searching for data in files using Cypress
I have the following scenario:
I have some .csv extension files saved in a directory.
I need to look for data that is in one of these files.
If I find the data, I don't need to consult the rest of the files.
Could anyone help? My code is in Cypress!
I'm trying like this:
cy.task('getFiles', 'batch/cer/22896431000382/unit/proccess')
        .then(result => {

          const x = result

for (let data = 0; data< x.length; data++) {
            cy.readFile(`batch/cer/22896431000382/unit/proccess/${x[data]}`)
              .then(txt => {

                expect(txt).to.contains('BUSINESS_AMOUNT');

              });
          };

The problem with this code is that it is validating each file.
And I just need to find the file that has the data I want.
Would anyone know how to help?!
Thanks!

It doesn't help me, unfortunately...

It looks very similar, you also have a loop you want to break early.

Can you explain what you're not getting about that answer?
